# How does the code actually for inserting a node when a node already exists

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nodes

After inserting a node, *sPtr which is the head pointer that points to the first node, how does the code actually work for inserting a second node? i understand the while loop is going through the nodes, checking if current is equals to null which is equals to the contents of *sPtr and if the value entered is bigger than current's data. but what i don't understand is the if else statement part after it. The if i get it's putting the newPtr to the beginning of the list, but the else part where previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr; how does this link the node existing *sPtr - > [existing node] to the newly created previous and current node that has jsut been assigned?

```
void insert(ListNode* *sPtr, char value)
{ 
   ListNode* newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); 

   if (newPtr != NULL) { 
      newPtr->data = value; 
      newPtr->nextPtr = NULL; 

      ListNode* previousPtr = NULL;
      ListNode* currentPtr = *sPtr;


      while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data) {
         previousPtr = currentPtr;            
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; 
      }                                          

      // insert new node at beginning of list
      if (previousPtr == NULL) { 
         newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
         *sPtr = newPtr;
      } 
      else { // insert new node between previousPtr and currentPtr
         previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
         newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
      } 
   } 
   else {
      printf("%c not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
   } 
}
```

i'm not sure if i'm making sense but it's jsut really confusing for me. Appreciate any explanation thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: The scenario of your question where `else` path will be entered is: add a second node at list tail. Then after while loop `previousPtr` points to first and only list node `previousPtr = *sPtr` and `currentPtr` points to list end `currentPtr = NULL`. Thus the `else` path will link next pointer of first/head list node to new list node. Next pointer of new list node will point to end of list (`NULL`).

Comment: So if we were to illustrate this, would *sPtr be pointing to anything? because i tried drawing it out to understand it and, and let's say previous has a as data and new has b as data, in the else statement, PreviousPtr has the first/existing node, and points to NewPtr, then NewPtr - > nextPtr now points to currentPtr which is equals to NULL. Prev - > New - > Current . So the *sPtr is not pointing to anything?

Comment: `*sPtr` doesn't change in `else` path and thus points to the same node after insertion. For your example if the list contains just one node with data "a" and you insert a node with data "b" then `*sPtr` points to node with data "a" before and after insertion. Node with data "b" will be just linked to list tail and list head which is `*sPtr` won't change.

Comment: Okay i think i got the wrong idea of nodes, so the current or previous are just pointers to nodes? They aren't nodes themselves, but just pointers like *sPtr?